# Reading an XML File in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I originally had a php file pulling in data from another php file. However, I have to change the second php file to an xml file. My question is, how do I read the string between certain tags in the php file using SimpleXML. For Example, here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<XMLExample>
  <Name>ExampleName</Name>
  <Info>ExampleInfo</Info>
  <KMLFile>ExampleKML</KMLFile>
</XMLExample>
```

I previously had this in my php file:

```
if(strlen($KMLFile)>0){
#echo "<a id=\"links\" href=\"/$place/Area/$KMLFile\">KML File</a> \n";
echo "<a id=\"links\" href=\"/media/$place/markup/xml/$KMLFile\">KML File</a> \n";
}
```

What I can't figure out is how to change the php code to read the data from the XML file. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. `note.xml` is your .xml file.

```
<?php
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    echo $xml->Name.'<br>';
    echo $xml->Info.'<br>';
    echo $xml->KMLFile;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works to output the xml perfectly. Any idea why I get the error: "Unexpected '{' within this part of my php code: `if(strlen($KMLFile)>0{echo "$KMLFile";}`? I set `$KMLFile = $xml->KMLFile;`

Comment: It's should be `if(strlen($KMLFile)>0){echo $KMLFile;}`

Comment: Oh. Wow. Missed that haha Thank you!